# onclick do not work IE11 (Windows 2016 server)

Tags: javascript

I am new in web development, let me know if I missed anything in my question.

Given JS code do not work on IE 11 (Windows 2016 Server), it is working fine on other browsers and giving me alert on my screen.

```html
<div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
  <a class="my_env_template dashboard-link" onclick="alert(123)">
    <span class="fa fa-2x dashboard-icon fa-clone" id="env_pref" aria-hidden="true"></span><br> Open Templates
  </a>
</div>
```

**Expected:** I was expecting Alert on my screen.

Please note that I'm running Windows 2016 server & IE with default settings, I did not change anything on server or browser configurations.

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: There are no errors on console :(

Comment: Check javascript is enable in ie. https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/internet-explorer

Comment: Try this:  onclick="alert(123);return false;"

Comment: @AravindSivam ...Thanks a lot ...you save my day .... it's working now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check javascript is enable in ie. 
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/internet-explorer